# SEO HTML for plain html css website

Tags: html, css, seo, joomla

This isn't really a programming question, but I couldn't think of a place where people can better answer my question then here.

I allways had a joomla website, for me it's good, but it's not very flexible.

My question is: In joomla you have some great SEO tools, like labeling or tagging your articles.

I'm planning to make my own css/html based website without a cms behind it.

Does anyone knows a labeling/tagging script whichcan be used for "normal" html/css based websites without for example joomla?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any tagging script would help you since you are only optimizing the content of your website, the best way would be to tag it all by yourself.

Even if such kind of scripts would exist, and even if you could configure the scripts manually for *this* or *that* keyword you won't get a better result than the one you could get by doing it all by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I can't vote up Vic because I Don't have the rep yet, but he is right. I am very familiar with Joomla and know what you're talking about. These are features you won't use/need in codding a static site.

What you need for an optimized static site is

- standards compliant html
- good informative and key phrase rich title tags
- good legible urls mysite.com/short-informative-text-here.html
- good meta descriptions
- proper use of h1,h2,h3
- informative relevant paragraph text

This is just a quick list I could think of off the top of my head, do these few things and I promise your site will do better than it will in most Joomla situations.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have a site with any amount of content on it you'll want to use a CMS. If you're set on writing a static html site, then you can easily create tags by hand, tags are essentially navigational links used to group articles, so for each tag you would create a page (like tag1.html) and each time you want something included in that tag you would open up tag1.html and add it to the top. When it gets too long and you want to paginate the tag1.html you just add tag1-1.html and a link to it on the bottom of tag1.html. This is not an efficient way to do things if you plan on adding content regularly, so I'd highly recommend looking at other CMS options that may be easier for you to customize many people recommend thesis theme for wordpress as it lets you customize just about anything from the admin dashboard (I have not used it myself but it seems like just about everyone and their brother is recommending specifically because of it's flexibility).